# Uploading Attachments to Salesforce API via Beatbox, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, salesforce, beatbox

I'm uploading documents to Salesforce using beatbox and python and the files are attaching correctly but the data contained within the files gets completely corrupted.

```
def Send_File():
    import beatbox
    svc = beatbox.Client()  # instantiate the object
    svc.login(login1, pw1)  # login using your sf credentials

    update_dict = {
        'type':'Attachment',
        'ParentId': accountid,
        'Name': 'untitled.txt',
        'body':'/Users/My_Files/untitled.txt',
            }
    results2 = svc.create(update_dict)
    print results2
```

output is:

```
    00Pi0000005ek6gEAAtrue
```

So things are coming through well, but when I go to the salesforce record 00Pi0000005ek6gEAA and view the file the contents of the file are:

```
   ˝KÆœ  Wøä ï‡Îä˜øHÅCj÷øaÎ0j∑ø∫{b∂Wù
```

I have no clue what's causing the issue and I can't find any situations where this has happened to other people

***Link to*** [SFDC Documentation on uploads](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 'body' value in the dictionary should be the base64 encoded contents of the file, not the file name. you need to read and encode the file contents yourself. e.g.

```
body = ""
with open("/Users/My_Files/untitled.txt", "rb") as f:
    body = f.read().encode("base64")

update_dict = {
    'type' : 'Attachement'
    'ParentId' : accountId,
    'Name' : 'untitled.txt',
    'Body' : body }

...
```

Docs about [Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm)

Comment: can see you are a salesforce guy which is good as some of us are newbies with it. I am reasonably sure the `body = ""` line at the top of your code can go away, the variable is being replaced underneath. You only do that if you are appending to a list or string.