# Uploading attachments to Salesforce with Beatbox - coming up blank

Tags: python, salesforce, base64, attachment, beatbox

Im trying to upload a folder full of emails to Salesforce, one email per case. The script does everything fine, but the emails it uploads are totally blank, and are 0 bytes.

Im pretty sure its something to do with the base64 encoding required to upload attachments, but I've tried everything to make it work.

I read this [Uploading Attachments to Salesforce API via Beatbox, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312509/uploading-attachments-to-salesforce-api-via-beatbox-python), which was helpful, but I cannot solve the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import wx
import email.parser
import os
import re
#import time
import beatbox
import base64




def browse(parent = None, message = 'Browse for the dealsheet folder'):
    app = wx.App()
    dialog = wx.DirDialog(None, "Choose a directory:",style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        return dialog.GetPath()
    dialog.Destroy()



service = beatbox.PythonClient()
service.serverUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/20.0'
loginresponse = service.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD') 


filespath = browse()

files = os.listdir(filespath)


global bodytext
global subject
global toAdd
global uploadfile

uploadfile = ''

for f in files:
    with open(filespath + '\\' + f, 'rb') as emailfile:
        message = email.message_from_file(emailfile)

        uploadfile = base64.b64encode(emailfile.read())


        subject = str(message.get('subject'))

        toAdd = str(message.get('to'))
        toAdd = re.findall(r'[\w\-][\w\-\.]+@[\w\-][\w\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]{1,4}', toAdd)[0]
        toAdd = toAdd[:-10]    # cut the email bits
        toAdd = toAdd.replace('.', ' ')
        toAdd = toAdd.title()
        print toAdd

        for part in message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                bodytext = part.get_payload()
                bodytext = str(bodytext)
                bodytext = unicode(bodytext, errors = 'replace')
#                print bodytext

    # LOG CASE

    details = {'type': 'Case', 'Reason': 'SFDC Admin', 'Origin': 'Email', 'Status': 'Awaiting Analysis', 'Description': ''}



    result = service.create(details)

    print 'log result = ', result[0]['success']


    #TRIAGE CASE

    details_triage = {'type': 'Case', 'id': result[0]['id'], 'Case_Triaged__c': 'True'}

    triage_result = service.update(details_triage)

    print 'triage result = ', triage_result[0]['success']

    url = 'https://naX.salesforce.com/{}'.format(triage_result[0]['id'])

    print url

    attachement_dict = {'type': 'Attachment', 'ParentId': triage_result[0]['id'], 'name': f, 'Body': uploadfile }


    if result[0]['success'] == True:        

        res = service.create(attachement_dict)

        print res
```

Comment: have you printed out uploadfile? seems like generating that is the problem.

Comment: I got it to work by opening the file, encoding to b64, closing, then opening again to parse the text. Now it all works perfectly.